# where is the meaning of what the ip command returns documented?

Tags: networking, ip

```
$ ip addr show enp1s0f0
4: enp1s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a6:b7:18:e4:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.149.1.3/16 scope global enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm curious as to why the state is `UP` between the angle brackets but `state DOWN` afterwards. the man page for ip(8) doesn't include a guide for interpreting its output.

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the netdevice man page?

Comment: no, but thanks for the tip. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually answer your question and not just point you to a man page, this means that the interface is administratively enabled (so it COULD be enabled), but the link is not active (ie down).